# Cannot update Group module with composer

Tags: 8, composer, group

We are using the Group module on our D8 site. We use composer to manage our modules and dependencies. I am somewhat of a composer novice, so it's possible that the solution is right in front of me, but I cannot see it.

The Group module refuses to be updated. It's currently at 1.0, and I'd like to update it to 1.4. I've tried running a simple `composer update drupal/group`, using `--with-dependencies` and `--with-all-dependencies` I've tried manually updating the `composer.json` to require both "1.4" and "^1.*". I've tried running the `why-not` command and all I get is "`There is no installed package depending on "drupal/group" in versions not matching 1.4`" Yet when I try to update the group module after changing the version in the composer file, all I get is the following.

```
$ composer update drupal/group --with-all-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies 
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Package flow/jsonpath is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use softcreatr/jsonpath instead.
Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/container instead.
Generating autoload files 35 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
```

If I try to update using the version in the command, however I get the following.

```
$ composer update drupal/group:1.4
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Unable to find a compatible set of packages based on your non-dev requirements alone.
Your requirements can be resolved successfully when require-dev packages are present.
You may need to move packages from require-dev or some of their dependencies to require.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/group 1.*, 1.4, found drupal/group[1.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
```

My composer.json is here, but I can't find anything that should be stopping this.

```
{
    "name": "drupal/recommended-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with a relocated document root",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
        "drupal/adaptivetheme": "^3.1",
        "drupal/address": "^1.8",
        "drupal/allowed_formats": "^1.3",
        "drupal/at_tools": "^3.2",
        "drupal/auto_entitylabel": "^3.0@beta",
        "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^4.0@beta",
        "drupal/calendar": "^1.0-alpha2",
        "drupal/conditional_fields": "^4.0@alpha",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8.9",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^8.9",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^8.9.17",
        "drupal/cshs": "^3.0",
        "drupal/date_recur": "^2.0",
        "drupal/date_recur_modular": "^2.0",
        "drupal/ds": "^3.5",
        "drupal/emptyparagraphkiller": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/encryption": "^1.0",
        "drupal/facets": "1.7",
        "drupal/facets_range_dropdowns": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/feeds": "^3.0@alpha",
        "drupal/feeds_ex": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/feeds_tamper": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/field_group": "^3.0",
        "drupal/field_permissions": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/file_extractor": "^2.0",
        "drupal/flag": "^4.0@beta",
        "drupal/fullcalendar_view": "^2.6",
        "drupal/group": "1.*",
        "drupal/group_permissions": "1.0.0-alpha7",
        "drupal/honeypot": "^1.30",
        "drupal/image_widget_crop": "^2.2",
        "drupal/inline_entity_form": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/login_destination": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/name": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/node_view_permissions": "^1.2",
        "drupal/optional_end_date": "^1.0",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.6",
        "drupal/publishcontent": "^1.2",
        "drupal/quick_node_clone": "^1.12",
        "drupal/redirect_after_login": "^2.5",
        "drupal/scheduler": "^1.1",
        "drupal/search_api": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/search_api_attachments": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/search_api_solr": "^4.2",
        "drupal/search_autocomplete": "^1.1",
        "drupal/simplify": "^1.2",
        "drupal/smart_trim": "^1.2",
        "drupal/swiftmailer": "^2.0",
        "drupal/twig_tweak": "^2.7",
        "drupal/twigsuggest": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/userprotect": "^1.1",
        "drupal/verf": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/view_unpublished": "^1.0",
        "drupal/views_bulk_operations": "^3.9",
        "drupal/views_exposed_filter_blocks": "^1.1",
        "drupal/views_ical": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/webform": "^5.8",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "drupal/devel": "^3.0.0-beta1",
        "drush/drush": "^10.3"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            },
            "file-mapping": {
                "[web-root]/.htaccess": false
            }
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
            "web/modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
        },
        "drupal-core-project-message": {
            "include-keys": ["homepage", "support"],
            "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "",
                "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",

                "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
                "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
                "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
                "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
                "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
                "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
                "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
            ]
        },
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "web/modules/contrib/webform/composer.json"
            ],
            "recurse": false,
            "replace": false,
            "ignore-duplicates": false,
            "merge-dev": true,
            "merge-extra": false,
            "merge-extra-deep": false,
            "merge-scripts": false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When this happens I typically will do this:

```
rm -rf vendor
rm -rf web/modules/contrib
composer clearcache
```

Then run your command again...

```
composer require 'drupal/group:^1.4'
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. This seemed to PARTIALLY work. It does seem to have updated the Group code to 1.4, but I still get a message, `"Unable to find a compatible set of packages based on your non-dev requirements alone.
Your requirements can be resolved successfully when require-dev packages are present.
You may need to move packages from require-dev or some of their dependencies to require.
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires drupal/group ^1.4, found drupal/group[1.0.0] but it does not match the constraint."` I'm confused why there would still be a problem if it was a cache issue

Comment: It wasn't a cache issue. You were requesting version `1.4`, which doesn't exist. The composer version would be `1.4.0`. The command Ryan gave you told you to get the version that STARTS with `1.4`, and therefore will find `1.4.0`. The carat (`^`) at the start tells the system 'STARTS WITH'.

Comment: @Jaypan OK. Now that I've updated the constraint to be ^1.4, would you be able to shed any light on why it's still giving the error in the comment above? Thanks for adding some clarification!

Comment: I would update your version of composer2 to the latest and then run `composer update`. When I look this stuff up I see an [issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9842) from around Q1 2021.

Comment: I'm already using version 2.1.5 of composer (what reports to be the most recent). That's what it reports when I run `composer self-update` at least.